# Master method - polynomially and asymptotically comparison

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

This might be a trivial question but want to ensure that I had sound understanding.
In the master method, when we try to solve recurrences, we typically compare two functions (asymptotically and polynomially) to determine which case of the master method is applicable.

For example, comparing $f(n)=n$ with $g(n)=n\log n$, we can say that $g(n)$ is asymptotically larger than $f(n)$, but the polynomial relation between the two functions cannot be determined because the ratio between the two functions is $\log n$ (which less than polynomial).

How about comparing $f_1(n)=n$ with $g_1(n)=n+\log n$? I expect $f_1(n)$ and $g_1(n)$ to be equal (asymptotically and polynomially) because $g_1(n) \in O(n)$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define asymptotic equivalence, but assuming the standard definition, which is that $f \sim g$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f}{g} = 1,$ then we have at once that $n \sim n + \log n$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n + \log n}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \frac{\log n}{n} = 1$.

Indeed, this limit of the ratio ($1$) turns out to be a polynomial, so they are also polynomially equivalent per your definition.